# How to add image in share twitter that are in drawable folder?

Tags: android, twitter, sharing

I need help to post text and images in drawable to twitter. Below is my code. I've tried and always failed. Can someone please help me.

```
private void ShareTwitter(){
        if (campaign == null) {
            finish();
        }else {
        String message =rewardItemTextView.getText().toString()+" "+"#TEST";
        try {
          Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

          Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.tes.activities/bbq.png");
//            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_assets/bbq");
          sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
          sharingIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android","com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
          sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message );
          sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
          startActivity(sharingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet"));
            startActivity(i);        
        }
```